# Connecting to an SQL Server 2012 DB in a LAN

Tags: android, localhost, sql-server-2012, router, lan

I have an Android application that connects to an SQL Server 2012 database on localhost.

When I run the emulator everything is fine.

I tried using Virtual Router Plus (http://virtualrouterplus.com/).

I am connecting with my android smartphone to this router through Wi-Fi.

What do I need to do so that I can access the database from Wi-Fi through the mobile?

Comment: Is the SQL server setup to allow remote connections? The default SQL installation only allows access from the local host.

Comment: @MBulava Yes, that option is checked (enabled).

Comment: Are you able to connect to the SQL server from another computer on the same network?

Comment: @MBulava I haven't tried that. I can access the database without any problems from a .NET Web App, and I was connecting perfectly to the Android application through the ADT Emulator, however, I cannot get it to work through my smart phone.

Comment: Local SQL connection and remote connections work differently. A web app and the Android Emulator would be considered a local connection which is why i suggested to see if you can connect to sql from another machine. That would narrow down the problem to the SQL server or the application code. Normally Local connections to SQL are established over a shared Memory connection which isn't avalible from a remote connection.  Plus there are firewall rules to consider which could be blocking the incomming connection.

Comment: How about trying to connect to sql using SSMS using the network IP address?  That way you don't have to get another machine involved.

Comment: The most likely cause for this I'm guessing is you don't have any external method to connect to SQL configured.  If you open the SQL configuration manager, Select your SQL instance in "SQL Server Network Configuration" I bet only Shared Memory is enabled.  I would enable TCP/IP and assign a fixed port, in the IP Address tab of the TCP/IP properties window, IPALL section.  Then you should be able to connnect either goign directly after the IP,Port or computer Name, Port combination.